# ¿ Como puedo obtener los datos duplicados en dos listas diferentes y los no duplicados en java?

Tags: java, lista, bucle-for, arraylist, array-bidimensional

Tengo dos listas:

**La tercera posición el turno M= matutino , V = vespertino**
La primer lista contiene estos datos:

```
edificio1,matematicas,M
edificio1,español,M
edificio1,ingles,M
edificio2,ingles,M
edificio2,matematicas,M
edificio4,ingles,M
```

La lista 2

```
edificio1,matematicas,V
edificio1,español,V
edificio1,ingles,V
edificio2,ingles,V
edificio2,matematicas,V
edificio5,ingles,V
```

**Salida esperada:**

```
Requiero separarlas por dos listas diferentes: 

1. Primer lista obtener los registros duplicados:  

edificio1,matematicas,M
edificio1,español,M
edificio1,ingles,M
edificio2,ingles,M
edificio2,matematicas,M
edificio1,matematicas,V
edificio1,español,V
edificio1,ingles,V
edificio2,ingles,V
edificio2,matematicas,V
```

```
2. Lista con registros no duplicados
edificio4,ingles,M
edificio5,ingles,V
```

De momento he realizado esto pero solo une las dos listas y no realiza la separación. 
**He pensado utilizar la posición 1 edificio como identificador pero de momento no se me ha ocurrido como , alguien tendrá alguna idea.**

```
    List<String> list1 = datoslista1;
        List<String> list2 = datoslista2;    
        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();   
        for (String element : list1) { 
            if (!list2.contains(element)) { 
                newList.add(element); 
            } 
        }   
        System.out.println(newList);
        //Concatena listas.       
        List<String> listFinal = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                             .distinct()
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
        //Ordena lista
        Collections.sort(listFinal);        
        //union de las dos listas 
        listFinal.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Salida de mi código**

```
edificio1,español,M
edificio1,español,V
edificio1,ingles,M
edificio1,ingles,V
edificio1,matematicas,M
edificio1,matematicas,V
edificio2,ingles,M
edificio2,ingles,V
edificio2,matematicas,M
edificio2,matematicas,V
edificio4,ingles,M
edificio5,ingles,V
```

Comment: ¿Cómo clasificas un registro duplicado? ¿Cual es el criterio? ¿La combinación de los 3 campos o sólo el campo de edificio?

Comment: Solo el campo edificio se considera como duplicado

Comment: Mi segunda pregunta va a tu código. Veo que `list1` es una `List<String>`, pero por la manera que describes, donde cada campo tiene un significado separado a mi me suena que debería ser una `List<List<String>>`. ¿Hay alguna especial razón por la que no separes los campos de cada línea?

Comment: no hay ninguna razón en especial,  de momento no he logrado realizar la separación que comento, solo lo que  mi codigo realiza es unir las dos listas , de ahi he estado intentando lograr la separación que de los registros duplicados y los no duplicados

Comment: Si el edificio se encuentra en ambas listas se considera duplicado se repita o no varias veces

Comment: Cuando no se considera duplicado es cuando el edificio solo existe en una lista , espero que me haya explicado un poco mejor de la problemática

Comment: Una idea pero profundamente teórica (me entra pereza escribirlo) sería implementar un array bidiminsional que mantenga los "atributos" separados mediante split con separador de "," (o cambiar el valor de la coma a un espacio y hacer un split normal). (Utilizando un bucle y hasNext();). Posteriormente solo haría falta comparar la posición n con las restantes, mediente otro bucle. Si se reptie, se cambia el valor del booleano (por ejemplo) y al final de este, un tercer bucle que compare el booleano anterior para implementarlo en la lista correspondiente. Esto es una idea general, espero que algú

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecciona el conjunto de edificios de cada una de las listas en dos sets diferentes. Luego une las listas para recorrerlas y verifica que cada elemento, o esté contenido en las dos o esté contenido en solo una de ellas usando `Collectors.partitioningBy`.

Puedes ejecutar un [demo online acá](https://www.onlinegdb.com/XSyQ9qh8f1):

```java
Set<String> set1 = list1.stream().map( s -> s.split( "," )[0] ).collect( Collectors.toSet() );
Set<String> set2 = list2.stream().map( s -> s.split( "," )[0] ).collect( Collectors.toSet() );

Map<Boolean, List<String>> result = Stream.concat( list1.stream(), list2.stream() )
        .collect( Collectors.partitioningBy( s -> {
            String key = s.split( "," )[0];
            return set1.contains( key ) && set2.contains( key );
        } ) );

var duplicados = result.get( true );
var distintos = result.get( false );
```

---

**EDIT**: Esta respuesta une las dos dos listas y encuentra los duplicados y únicos en la unión.

```
Map<String, Integer> frequency = Stream.concat( list1.stream(),list2.stream() )
        .map( s -> s.split( "," )[0] )
        .collect( Collectors.toMap( Function.identity(), v -> 1, Integer::sum ) );

Map<Boolean, List<String>> result = Stream.concat( list1.stream(),list2.stream() )
        .collect( Collectors.partitioningBy( s -> frequency.get( s.split( "," )[0] ) > 1 ) );

List<String> duplicados = result.get( true );
List<String> distintos = result.get( false );
```

La idea es sacar la frecuencia de cada entrada de la tabla. La variable `frecuency` contendrá un `Map` cuya clave será el edificio, y cuyo valor es la cantidad de veces que se repite este edificio.

Luego hacemos una partición separando los que se repiten una sola vez, de los que se repiten muchas veces usando `Collectors.partitioningBy`.

Te dejo [un ejemplo](https://onlinegdb.com/XSyQ9qh8f1) que puedes ejecutar online.

Comment: Una duda https://onlinegdb.com/SuysWOOiK en este caso la lista1 contiene edificio1 tres veces, pero la lista2 no la contiene , entonces debe de aplicar como no duplicado, deberia mandar edificio1 a los no duplicados pero los manda a los duplicados ya que no se encuentra en la lista2 ?

Comment: @Juan ahora que especificas ese caso me doy cuenta que interpreté mal tu enunciado y da la casualidad que para el ejemplo que pusiste funcionaba, por eso no me dí cuenta. Pensé se trataba de unir las dos listas, y ver lo que se repetía y lo que no, pero ya veo cómo es en realidad. Checa estos cambios que creo que sí se ajustan a lo que quieres. Me dices si es eso para editar la respuesta https://onlinegdb.com/LLgy9C2cp

Comment: Si justo esto es, he realizado varias pruebas con estos ajustes que realizaste y realiza la función que trate de describir , lo siento quizá mi explicación fue confusa. pero con esta nueva respuesta se resuelve mi problema muchas gracias.!!